# Does AWS Lightsail support cloud-config user data?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-lightsail

I have the following Terraform structure for provisioning an AWS Lightsail instance:

```
resource "aws_lightsail_instance" "instance" {
  name = "instance"
  availability_zone = "${data.aws_region.current.name}a"
  blueprint_id = "ubuntu_20_04"
  bundle_id = "micro_2_0"
  key_pair_name = aws_lightsail_key_pair._initial_key_pair.name

  user_data = data.template_file.script.rendered
}

resource "aws_lightsail_key_pair" "initial_key_pair" {
  name       = "initial_key_pair"
  public_key = file(var.ubuntu_user_ssh_public_key_path)
}

data "template_file" "script" {
  template = file("${path.module}/cloud-init.tpl")

  vars = {
    nginx_conf_base64_content = base64gzip(base64decode(filebase64("${path.module}/nginx.conf")))
  }
}
```

So I am trying to utilize the cloud-config / cloud-init, in this simplified case to copy the file from local machine to the AWS Lightsail instance during `terraform apply`. Contents of the `cloud-init.tpl`:

```
write_files:
    - path: /home/ubuntu/config
      permissions: '0644'
      owner: root:root
      encoding: gz+b64
      content: ${nginx_conf_base64_content}
```

This, however, does not work. Inspecting `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log` gives me this error log:

```
Lightsail: SSH CA Public Key registered.
Lightsail: SSH-RSA added.
Lightsail: sshd restarted.
/var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/part-001: 27: write_files:^M: not found
/var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/part-001: 28: -: not found
/var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/part-001: 29: permissions:: not found
/var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/part-001: 30: owner:: not found
/var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/part-001: 31: encoding:: not found
```

The resultant contents of `/var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/part-001`:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo Lightsail: Starting Instance Initialization.

cat > /etc/ssh/lightsail_instance_ca.pub << EOF
ssh-rsa AAAAB....
echo Lightsail: SSH CA Public Key created.

echo >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config
echo 'TrustedUserCAKeys /etc/ssh/lightsail_instance_ca.pub' >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config
echo Lightsail: SSH CA Public Key registered.

version_string=$(ssh -V 2>&1)
current_version=$(echo "$version_string" | sed 's/.*OpenSSH_//; s/[p\|,].*//')
min_version="7.9"
versions="$current_version
$min_version"

if [ "$(echo "$versions" | sort -Vr | head -n1)" = "$current_version" ]; then
  echo 'CASignatureAlgorithms +ssh-rsa' >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config
  echo Lightsail: SSH-RSA added.
fi

service sshd restart
echo Lightsail: sshd restarted.

write_files:
    - path: /home/ubuntu/config
      permissions: '0644'
      owner: root:root
      encoding: gz+b64
      content: H4sIAAA...
```

As we can see, the custom cloud-init declaration is somehow mixed with some shell code that initializes the instance which does not look right.

Is there anything I am doing wrong? The similar config works like a charm with the EC2 instances (I am using `user_data_base64` there though), but does not work with Lightsail. I can imagine I can provide some shell code in `user_data` but this of course is way much less powerful and convenient compared to cloud-init config. Any ideas on how to make cloud-init work with Lightsail using Terraform?

Comment: It seems that cloud-config format is not supported ...